# Charge Enclosed by Rectangular Conductor

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

I would like to determine the charge enclosed in an infinitely long solid rectangular conductor using Maxwells Equations.

Here's what I've gotten, but I don't know if its correct.

$\int_C\ E•dA = Q(enc)/ε_0$

$ E = Q(enc)/[2•(LW+LH+WH)•ε_0]$

where: L = length, W = width, H = height

Is this accurate?

Comment: You've made an assumption that the electric field is constant on the surface. Is that true? And how is this problem related to math? Why not on physics.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @Andrei For the most part, yes. But every conductor has an insulator wrapped around it. I posted this problem here because I'm interested in the mathematical aspect of it, not the physics aspect.